# Doctrine returns result only with empty cache

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Hi I'm doing a very simple query with Doctrine but it returns results only when I delete the cache : `app/cache/`

The problem is not Mysql because I get results with the query that Doctrine makes.
I have to find some contacts

```
    $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder($alias);

    $qb->select('c');
    $qb->addSelect('cc');
    $qb->addSelect('cp');

    $qb->leftJoin("c.companyContacts", "cc");
    $qb->leftJoin("cc.company", "cp");
    $qb->leftJoin("c.accessions", "a");
    $qb->where('a.createdAt ="2014-08-20"');
```

It works when I load the page for the first time, then, I have not results. 
The profiler shows results in the explain of the query :

[image]

**EDIT**

The problem is the date, when I try it with another attribute it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution found:** 
No single or double quotes for dates in `Doctrine`